# tex4ebook: generating broken ebooks when there are footnotes for title or author

Tags: titles, author, tex4ebook

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{Hello}%\footnote{Just a test}}
\author{Somebody\footnote{Anonymous.}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It compiles with errors

```
line 13 column 1 - Error: unexpected </manifest> in <dc:title>
line 21 column 1 - Error: unexpected </package> in <dc:title>
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.
```

and the generated epub file is broken.

Any workaround? or this is in fact nonstandard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epub file contains some metadata in the `content.opf` file. For example author and title should be present in plain text format. Any macro that could produce some additional markup needs to be redefined in a `@author`, resp. `@title` configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{@author}{\let\footnote\@gobble}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration redefines `\footnote` to eat one argument and print nothing. This change is present only in the OPF file, so the footnote will still work in the document.